# Ignored YAML tag

Tags: go, parsing, yaml

I have config.yml file:

```
vcenter:
  connection: https 
  hostname: vcenter.mydomain.lan
  username: readonlyauto@vsphere.local
  password: mypasspord
  port: 443

EsxiExcludeDatastores:
  - datastore1
  - datastore2

EsxiExcludeDatastores2:
  datastores:
    - datastore1
    - datastore2
```

I'm trying to parse it with "gopkg.in/yaml.v2"

I created struct:

```
type FileConfig struct {
    Vcenter struct {
        ConnectionType string `yaml:"connection"`
        Hostname string `yaml:"hostname"`
        Username string `yaml:"username"`
        Password string `yaml:"password"`
        Port int `yaml:"port"`
    } `yaml:"vcenter"`
    EsxiExcludeDatastores struct {
        Datastores []string `yaml:"EsxiExcludeDatastores"`
    }
    EsxiExcludeDatastores2 struct {
        Datastores []string `yaml:"datastores"`
    } `yaml:"EsxiExcludeDatastores2"`
}

var AppConfig FileConfig
```

After parsing, I print results:

```
    fmt.Println("Num of EsxiExcludeDatastores.Datastores = ", len(AppConfig.EsxiExcludeDatastores.Datastores))
    fmt.Println("Num of EsxiExcludeDatastores2.Datastores = ", len(AppConfig.EsxiExcludeDatastores2.Datastores))


Num of EsxiExcludeDatastores.Datastores =  0
Num of EsxiExcludeDatastores2.Datastores =  2
```

Can you help me, where I did mistake in EsxiExcludeDatastores struct? As you see, everything is fine with EsxiExcludeDatastores2, but EsxiExcludeDatastores is empty.

I tried to do this in different ways, but with no result ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.

To "promote" yaml struct tag(s) to the "parent" field, add:

```
EsxiExcludeDatastores struct {
    Datastores []string `yaml:"EsxiExcludeDatastores"`
} `yaml:",inline"`   // <- this
```

https://play.golang.org/p/S7QxGaspTyN

---

From the [yaml.v2](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Marshal) docs, a struct tag that uses the `inline` flag does the following:

> Inline the field, which must be a struct or a map, causing all of its
> fields or keys to be processed as if they were part of the outer
> struct. For maps, keys must not conflict with the yaml keys of other
> struct fields.